# Joomla 2.5+: Creating an Account and Log in within the same Controller Call

Tags: joomla, authentication, account

I have created a from with a user registration. When processing the form within the controller, I want the user to be logged in afterwards. Account creation works fine, but logging right afterwards fails:

```
function processForm($username,$first_name,$last_name,$email,$password,$groups) {
    jimport('joomla.user.helper');
    $app     = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $user     = new JUser();

    $b= array();
    $user->bind($b);
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->name     = $first_name." ".$last_name;
    $user->set('id',0);

    $date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $user->set('registerDate', $date);
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->set('password',JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password,JUserHelper::getSalt()));
    $user->set('block', '0');
    $user->save();

    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        JUserHelper::addUserToGroup($user->id, $group);
    }
    $app->login(array("username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: $session =JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('user', $user); works instead of $app->login(array("username"=>$username,"password"=>$password));